# difference between v-for structures

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Could someone explain what is the difference between those 2 ***v-for*** structures:

```html
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item">
</li>
```

and

```html
<li v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
</li>
```

Comment: They both are same, `i` parameter is the `index` you get inside a loop 
so if you have 10 elements .. index would be 0,1..9 inside a loop

Comment: the `key` attribute requires a unique value with each iteration. It might be possible that the `item` value is not unique every time and is totally dependent on the iterating `items` data which is passed to it. If you have something like `item.id` in the item object, then you can use that too! Ref: [v-for key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)

Comment: @bawina I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 2):

Vue requires all items inside a `v-for` to be "*key*-ed". The key is used to uniquely identify each element. This doesn't mean Vue will break if you don't use a `key`. It will warn it might not be able to detect all changes.

The *"key"* is particularly useful and important to Vue, as it allows it to skip re-rendering items which have not changed.

When duplicate keys are detected across a rendered collection, Vue will issue a warning.

Another Vue recommendation is that the "*key*"s are **primitives** (`string`s or `number`s). When you specify non-primitive keys Vue will, again, issue a warning.

Given all the above recommendations, when rendering an array of unique primitives, using

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item" />
```

...is perfectly acceptable, as it meets the requirements: each key is primitive and unique.

Therefore, if you change the order of the items, Vue will be able to re-use the existing DOM elements and perform any move transitions (if you specified any). Testing this is actually fun. Consider [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/v2.vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-list-move-transitions), taken from the Vue documentation. Open it and, using dev-tools, change any of the rendered items' `color` to `red`. Then click the shuffle button. You'll see Vue re-uses the element and your custom change is kept, as the item is moved around.

---

When you're dealing with collections of non-primitives, or with collections of non-unique primitives, Vue still expects you to provide a unique primitive key for each item. Ideally, you should have a unique identifier (e.g: `item.id`). This is the typical solution and meets all requirements.

Sometimes, you don't have a unique identifier on each item, and an easy solution is to just use the items' position in the array as identifier (key):

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" />
```

However, remember this can become problematic, particularly in cases where you change the order of the items after they're rendered and expect Vue to react to this change. It won't! Because Vue only watches the keys. When you swap items, keys don't change. only values do, so Vue won't re-render.

Official docs here:

- Vue2 list rendering: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html
- Vue3 list rendering: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#list-rendering

---

As an example of how useful and powerful keys are when rendering, have a look at [this virtual scroller](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-sara-3jpe7).
Open the dev tools, inspect any cell and then scroll, while keeping the devtools open. You'll notice rows and columns only get updated when they change (each element flashes swiftly when it gets updated).
If you look into [the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-sara-3jpe7?file=/components/GridScroller.vue), you'll notice keys are dynamic. So you'd expect the first `<div>` in `rows` to always render the contents of the first object in `rows` and swap contents whenever another object takes first place in the array.
Thanks to the keys, Vue keeps the same `<div>` throughout its journey across the screen and only discards it after it leaves the scrolling window. As you scroll up, new `<div>`s are prepended to parent and as you scroll down new `<div>`s are appended, while the top ones are discarded.
This allows scrolling 100k rows (and 1 billion cells) smoothly (well, only in theory; in practice - we're only rendering as many cells as the screen can fit + 1 extra row + 1 extra column).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the v-for iterates over all elements of `items`. It assigns the `:key` to the item itself. This is not ideal if you have duplicate elements in `items`, because each `:key` should be unique.

In the second case, v-for also iterates over all elements of `items`, but it introduces another variable named `i`, which represents the numerical index of the `item` in `items`. This index is then assigned to `:key`. This is better, because the indexes can't be duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

As the purpose of `:key` attribute is to give `a hint for Vue virtual DOM algorithm about change detection happen`. Essentially, it helps Vue identify what's changed and what hasn't.

To understand it better I am adding the uses of both the scenarios **:**

- `:key="item"` - If item is having unique value. So that each iterated element will get assigned with unique key.

  [image: Demo screenshot]
- `:key="index"` - If item is not having unique value. Hence, to assigned unique key to each iterated element we are using `index`.

  [image: Demo screenshot]